# Speeding Up Simple Animations

Tags: animation

I'm using Blender (2.79) to do some really basic text overlays on video using the blender internal rendering engine. (I can't see how to attach the blend file - sorry. But just imagine some text (3 words), orthographic projection camera with a simple node setup to composite a video behind it - picture of it attached.[image]).

The issue I'm having is that the render times seem long, given the simplicity of what I'm doing. I expected (or was hoping) them to be close to real time, but each frame is taking anywhere from 0.3-0.5s and it doesn't seem possible to reduce it any further!

I've turned off shadows, ambient occlusion etc. Everything I've found about speeding up render times seems to relate to complex scenes.

It seems there's something of a scene load overhead (there's a video background) and so I was wondering if Blender has an option to keep the scene loaded?

I'd wondered about using the game engine to output frames, I've seen some examples of scripts to do this, but I want to do it from the command line, and I'm not sure how that would work.

Any ideas?

Mike

Comment: Cycles, EEVEE, Internal? Give us more information and maybe share the file or post some screenshots of your scene.

Comment: Good point - sorry for the vagueness of my post above. I'll add some more details to my post. Thanks!

Comment: Added some more information. I hope that's of some help!